# Alternatives to ASP.NET (core) Identity framework

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-identity

I develop ASP.NET (core) web applications that need user authentication and authorization. Until now, I have been using the Identity Framework Membership System that is part of ASP.NET. However, I want to ask if this is a good approach and, of course, what is a better alternative. I have seen other services like Auth0 but I wonder if services like this are worth impementing.

I will very much appreciate your feedback.

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado